# Best way to flow content out of the body

Tags: css, css-float, positioning, css-position

I'm working on a blog layout, where some info (blue box) is taken out from the post's body like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rhr96/

What is the best of doing that?

Currently I'm doing:

```
position: absolute;  
margin-left: negative value;
```

to flow the blue box to the left.

But I could also do:

```
position: relative;  
float: left;
right: some px;
```

Any of these considered better? Or are there any other method?

Comment: I would prefer position absolute and a negative left margin, but the best is to structure your html so you don't have to "take it out"

Comment: Yeah, but that's on purpose. I want to diplay something in that box in a way that it is next to the body.

Comment: I meant something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BBTRD/1/ The dark grey area is still your "body" and main content area but it is more semantic and doesn't use negative margins

Comment: thanks! are negative margins considered bad?

Comment: Not really, they are generally fine. But if something can be done more semantically that doesn't require moving something out of its "flowing" position I'm generally all for that

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer: `POSITION ABSOLUTE`

Reason: Designers use `position: absolute` because that is the right way to take out the element from the normal document flow, using `float: left;` wont take out the blue box out of the document flow...

Edit: Just understood what you actually wanted, here I've made a new 1, you can check it out..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qbtKm/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="content">This is a question</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin: 30px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.block {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    width: 410px;
    float: right;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: @Andy where some info (blue box) is **taken out** from the post's body

Comment: Thanks!
I've just looked at the answer structure for stackoverflow: the answer's body and the upvote thing is separated with table structure.
maybe that's the 3rd method.

Comment: @marchello oh now I got you, so you need a layout like stackoverflow...you can check my answers..I answered it previously..

Comment: yes, but I don't want to hide it. I want it to like the way in my original fiddle, I was just curious what is the best way of doing that . maybe this table solution in stackoverflow is better browser support?
@Alien: checking it

Comment: @marchello tables should be ignored, it was the stone age approach for designing layouts, you've a powerful CSS now, you should go for div's unless and until the data is not in a tabular format

Comment: thanks I can see it now.
so the reason for using tables at stackoverflow is that the data coming from the database fits better with tables than with divs?

Comment: @marchello I don't know why they are using tables, may be they feel easier to design for this specific purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way of doing this, may actually be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YuZ8d/) (well, I say best, I guess that's a matter of opinion in most cases)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outside">
        hi
    </div>
    <div class="inside">
        <p>Blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { margin: 20px auto; width: 400px; }

.outside { background: #d8d8d8; float: left; margin: 0 5px 0 0; padding: 5px; }
.inside { background: #000; color: #fff; margin: 5px 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

Obviously you can repeat this multiple times on the same page (as I imagine you may if this is for blog posts)

**EDIT:** My answer uses `floats` to take the element out of the normal flow, the use of `overflow: hidden` on the content means that it doesn't wrap underneath the floated element.

(If you don't know much about `overflow` I'd suggest [reading about it](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/), it can be useful for all sorts of things, e.g. float clearing)

Comment: thanks, yes exactly this will be a blog post. post body and next to its left the date.